# BizTalk: conditional looping on 2 levels

Tags: loops, dictionary, conditional-statements, biztalk

I need to use conditional looping on two levels in a BizTalk map, but the condition I use for creating the parent data inhibits the Creation of the child data.

Any ideas on how to map the following in BizTalk mapper:

### Input

Comment: <Group> and <Row> elements are on the same level.

> ```
>  <Line>
>       <Name>Group</Name>
>       <RowNo>1</RowNo>
>  </Line>
>  <Line>
>       <Name>Row</Name>
>       <RowNo>1</RowNo>
>  </Line>
>  <Line>
>       <Name>Row</Name>
>       <RowNo>2</RowNo>
>  </Line>
>  <Line>
>       <Name>Group</Name>
>       <RowNo>2</RowNo>
>  </Line>
>  <Line>
>       <Name>Row</Name>
>       <RowNo>1</RowNo>
>  </Line>
>  <Line>
>       <Name>Row</Name>
>       <RowNo>2</RowNo>
>  </Line>
> ```

### Output

Comment: The <Row> element should be under the <Group> element.

> ```
>  <Group>
>       <Name>Group</Name>
>       <RowNo>1</RowNo>
>       <Row>
>            <Name>Row</Name>
>            <RowNo>1</RowNo>
>       </Row>
>       <Row>
>            <Name>Row</Name>
>            <RowNo>2</RowNo>
>       </Row>
>  </Group>
>  <Group>
>       <Name>Group</Name>
>       <RowNo>2</RowNo>
>       <Row>
>            <Name>Row</Name>
>            <RowNo>1</RowNo>
>       </Row>
>       <Row>
>            <Name>Row</Name>
>            <RowNo>2</RowNo>
>       </Row>
>  </Group>
> ```

Creating the child element <Row> in the output is pretty straightforward, I use a condition that checks if input <Line/Name>="Row" and then map the content in input element <Line> to output element <Row>.

The problem is when I use the same logic to create the output parent element <Group>. If I check if input <Line/Name>="Group" this will correctly create the output element <Group>, but when this condition is not fullfilled (ie Name=Row) this will also inhibit the creation of the childelement <Row>, hence resulting in the following output:

> ```
>  <Group>
>       <Row />
>       <Name>Group</Name>
>       <RowNo>1</RowNo>
>  </Group>
>  <Group>
>       <Row />
>       <Name>Group</Name>
>       <RowNo>2</RowNo>
>  </Group>
> ```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Or is this the case that will force me into the XSLT jungle?

I can solve this by using an orchestration, but it is desired that I run this as a map on the Receive port so I very much would like to solve this in one single map.

Comment: Let yourself be "forced into the XSLT jungle" and you have a simple, maintainable solution in no time. ;)

Answer (score 1):

xslt is not *that* difficult. There are many instances when you will need it. This is one of them. Do yourself a favor and try it. Really!

- Right click on the transform
- hit validate transform in the right click menu
- save the two files it produces
- open the transform. Left click on the background grid.
- Enter the names of the two files as external xslt and xml in the properties window.
- update your xslt to get what you need
- debug xslt (from the right click menu) is your friend